# SDL Mixer Audio Randomly Gets Louder

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I wrote a C++ game using SDL 2.0 and SDL_Mixer. Sometimes when playing audio a sound randomly becomes louder. It seems to be when multiple sounds play at the same time, but I'm not sure why.

Here's the two functions I'm calling to play sounds in my game:

```cpp
void Sounds::play(Mix_Chunk* sound)
{
    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound, 0);
}

void Sounds::play(Mix_Music* music)
{
    Mix_PlayMusic(music, 0);
}
```

Comment: Does it get louder when multiple sounds start playing or when one of them stops playing?  Does everything get louder or just one of the sounds?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it happens when multiple start playing, and I'm pretty sure it's just one of the sounds that gets louder. It seems to be the one that starts playing when there is already another playing.

Comment: Can it be played twice accidentally?

Comment: Yep, that’s by design though. I made an Arkanoid clone and there’s a ball destroying tons of bricks quickly and each hit plays a sound. Most play the same sound.